# What is the "anatomy" of transcriptional regulation in Archaea?

Tags: transcription, gene-regulation, eukaryotic-cells, transcription-factor, archaea

I want to know what are the DNA elements that are recognized by transcription factors in Archaea and so what is the "anatomy" of transcriptional regulation in this case.

I found in this paper by [Alexandra M. Gehring et al.](https://journals.asm.org/doi/epub/10.1128/JB.00255-16) that the process of initiation of transcription in archaea is governed by TATA-binding protein (TBP), Archaeal transcription factor B (TFB), and Archaeal transcription factor E (TFE). These constitute the *basal transcription factors* and transcription initiation is regulated by DNA elements that are recognized by basal transcription factors that recruit the enzyme RNA Polymerase (RNAP) that will copy DNA into RNA. There  are  four  DNA  elements  currently  known  to  regulate  archaeal  transcription  initiation: the **TATA-box** located approximately 25 bp upstream of the site of transcription  initiation;  the **TFB  recognition  element  (BRE)** located immediately upstream of the TATA box; the **initiator element (INR)** located  within  the  initially  transcribed  region,  and  the **promoter  proximal  element  (PPE)** located  between  the  TATA  box and the site of transcription initiation.

This seems very similar to the eukaryotic system and, in fact, also the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeal_transcription) page tells that  *the core machinery is more similar to eukaryotic transcription* (with respect to bacteria).

Moreover, the first paper that I linked also tells that it is probable that some *archaeon-specific factors await discovery* for the elongation and termination steps of transcription.

Now, I started to search if Archaea have *enhancers* and *silencers* like the eukaryotic genes but I could not find anything. Since *the core machinery is more similar to eukaryotic transcription*, can I assume that there are enhancers and repressors and that the main pattern of DNA elements necessary for transcription and transcription regulation is that of eukaryotes? Maybe, the reason why I do not find the answer to my question in Google is that some *archaeon-specific factors await discovery*. Indeed, Archaea are, in general, often called the "blind spots" of natural diversity because of lack of knowledges about them.

Also if you have a look at the [Promoter (genetics) Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)), there is a list of elements of promoter relative to Eukaryotes and Bacteria, but nothing about Archaea... So is it completely wrong to look at the eukaryotic elements and explanations of this page, for example, as *(at least) probably* valid also for Archaea ?

Thank you in advance.